# PowerShell Set-Location to file server PermissionDenied under Enter-PSSession

Tags: powershell, file-server

In our company, we have a fileserver from where I want to run scripts to update remote computers.

All computers are in a domain.

When I'm on my computer and execute (PowerShell run as Admin or not)

```
Set-Location -Path "\\fileserver.company.org\scripts_folder\"
```

it works

When I'm on remote computer (same subnet) same user
the same above command works.

But when I do

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName PC-NAME -Credential my_username
Set-Location -Path "\\fileserver.company.org\scripts_folder\"
```

The Set-Location returns

```
Set-Location : Access is denied
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\fileserver.company.org\scripts_folder\:String) [Set-Location], Unauthoriz
   edAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

Why is access denied? Under what user is PowerShell running when I `Enter-PSSession`?

Comment: If you really want to see what is happening in each use case, try using the Trace-Command cmdlet to get that detail. Set-Location is working as designed. Locations are local to you. In explicit remoting, you are not on your local system.

Comment: Trace-Command -Name CommandDiscovery -Expression {Set-Location -Path "\\fileserver.company.org\scripts_folder\"} -PSHost
   last 4 returns before Access is denied are: 
DEBUG: CommandDiscovery Information: 0 : Looking up command: Set-StrictMode
DEBUG: CommandDiscovery Information: 0 : Cmdlet found: Set-StrictMode  Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetStrictModeCommand
if I do Set-StrictMode -Off it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me this looks like a `double hop` or `second hop problem`

> The "second hop problem" refers to a situation like the following:
>
> 1. You are logged in to ServerA.
> 2. From ServerA, you start a remote PowerShell session to connect to ServerB.
> 3. A command you run on ServerB via your PowerShell Remoting session attempts to access a resource on ServerC.
> 4. Access to the resource on ServerC is denied, because the credentials you used to create the PowerShell Remoting session are not
>    passed from ServerB to ServerC.

In your case your Computer would be ServerA, the Computer where you enter the Session on is ServerB and the fileserver is ServerC

If your Computers are on WMF 3.0 or later, You can create a `PSSessionConfiguration` with credentials tied to it. You can then use this configuration when you create a Remote Session on ServerB

To create the configuration, run this command in an elevated PowerShell on ServerB, and use a Credential that has permission to access the ressources on ServerC

```
Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name AdminCredConfig -RunAsCredential 'domain\mydomainaccount' -Force
```

Then you can specify the created `PSSessionConfiguration` when you enter the Session

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName ServerB -Credential my_username -ConfigurationName AdminCredConfig
Set-Location -Path "\\fileserver.company.org\scripts_folder\"
```

This is the easiest way to solve your Problem in my opinion. However there are multiple different ways to get past the second hop problem, for example CredSSP. you can read about them in the [MS Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7)

For Computers that are not on WMF 3.0 or later, you will have to [Pass credentials inside the Invoke-Command Script Block](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7#pass-credentials-inside-an-invoke-command-script-block), which is also easy to achieve but is not very elegant and requires awkward coding.

Alternatively, look for a way where you don't even need to worry about the second hop problem.

Answer (score -1):

I found the root of my problem. It's called "second hop problem"

> The "second hop problem" refers to a situation like the following:
>
> 1. You are logged in to ServerA.
> 2. From ServerA, you start a remote PowerShell session to connect to ServerB.
> 3. A command you run on ServerB via your PowerShell Remoting session
>    attempts to access a resource on ServerC.
> 4. Access to the resource on ServerC is denied, because the credentials
>    you used to create the PowerShell Remoting session are not passed
>    from ServerB to ServerC.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7